# How to open mutiple dialog using Primefaces dialog framework

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, dialog

I'm new to JSF and Primefaces, I need to open a dialog containing some sort of search result information whenever a search button was click. Previously open dialog should always be displayed unless user close it, so I could have multiple dialog open.

I'm using the below technologies, and my problem is I only want to use a single xhtml template for the dialog that I call using the Primefaces dialog framework. Any idea how to achieve what I want?

- JBoss EAP 6.2
- Primefaces 4.0
- JSF 2.2

I have a sample code that I'm trying to work on as a POC below. It is working fine I can display the first dialog, but I no longer have an idea how to open another dialog when the search button was click again.

home.xhtml

```
<div id="searchBtnDiv">
            <p:commandButton id="queryNetworkElem" value="Search" ajax="true"    actionListener="#{searchBean.querySubmit}" />  
            <p:commandButton id="advanceQuery" value="Advance Search" ajax="true" actionListener="#{searchBean.querySubmit}" /> 
        </div>
```

SearchBean.java

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "searchBean")
    public class SearchBean{
    ...
    public void generateSearchDialog(String searchParam) throws IOException{

        System.out.println("opening dialog");
        testMessage = "testing ";


        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("test");

    } 
    ...
    }
```

test.xhtml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

   <h:head>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
       <h1><p:outputLabel value="#{searchBean.testMessage}"/></h1>
        <p:commandButton value="test" />        
   </h:body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method generateSearchDialog only displays the p:dialog with id="test" on your page. What this will do is that it'll open that dialog and only that one (meaning that, if you close the dialog and call the method again, it'll be reopened).

From what I understand, you want to create new Dialog instances with every call to generateSearchDialog?

If you want to do this, you need to create new dialog instances dynamically. In your web page, create a container for these dialogs (ie. a panelGroup) and every time the method is called it will create a new Dialog instance. Keep in mind that creating dialogs programmatically in the backing bean is not a good practice, but it will help you achieve this. Now, for this to work, the dialog's header should be dynamic (maybe add a counter?)
Your backing bean would look something like this:

```
UIComponent panelGroup = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getViewRoot().findComponent("dialogContainer");
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.setId("newDialogInstance" + counter);
dialog.setVisible(true); //add whatever code you like
...
panelGroup.getChildren().add(dialog);
...
//update the WHOLE panel
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("dialogContainer");
// OR openDialog your new Dialog.
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("newDialogInstance" + counter);
...
counter++;
```

Comment: What about creating that dialog from an include (template) file?

Comment: I'd have to try that. Don't really know if there's a JSF equivalent for Android's inflate (which is basically what you want to do)...

Comment: Well with the single dialog option I'm using: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("templates/filename"); (with or without arguments) and it includes "templates/filename.xhtml".

Comment: I don't know if that would apply. OP's question said that multiple dialogs could be open. Unless you find a way to dynamically inject a new id on the template file...

Comment: Suppose I could. Then how would I do it?

Comment: Like I said before: I'd have to try that / research about that. Don't really know if there's a JSF equivalent for Android's inflate (which is basically what you want to do)...

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample code which has a List of Persons. Every time when User clicks on the person, a new dialog opens

xhtml code:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable value="#{mbean.personList}" var="person">
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <p:commandLink value="#{person.name}" 
                update=":form">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{mbean.selectedPerson}"
                    value="#{person}" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Country">
            #{person.country}
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <!-- <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/test.xhtml" /> -->
    <ui:repeat var="d" value="#{mbean.personList}">

        <p:dialog id="_#{d.getId()}"  modal="false" width="500" height="500" widgetVar="Jag:#{d.getId()}">
        <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{mbean.handleClose}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{d.getName()}"></h:outputLabel>

        </p:dialog>
    </ui:repeat>

</h:form>
```

Java code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mbean")
```

@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

```
private List<Person> personList;
private Person selectedPerson;
private String dialogName;
private static int count=0;
private Map<Integer, String> dialogRemover = new HashMap<>();




public Map<Integer, String> getDialogRemover() {
    return dialogRemover;
}

public void setDialogRemover(Map<Integer, String> dialogRemover) {
    this.dialogRemover = dialogRemover;
}


public String getDialogName() {
    return dialogName;
}

public void setDialogName(String dialogName) {
    this.dialogName = "jag"+String.valueOf(count++);
}

public TestBean() {
    personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    personList.add(new Person(6,"Aaa", "UK"));
    personList.add(new Person(7,"Bbb", "Australia"));
    personList.add(new Person(8,"Ccc", "Asia"));

}

public List<Person> getPersonList() {
    return personList;
}

public void setPersonList(List<Person> personList) {
    this.personList = personList;
}

public Person getSelectedPerson() {
    return selectedPerson;
}

public void handleClose(CloseEvent event){
    System.out.println("eventZ: "+event.getComponent().getId());
    System.out.println("handle close event "+event.getComponent().getClientId());
    String[] array = event.getComponent().getClientId().split(":");
    dialogRemover.remove(Integer.parseInt(array[2]));
    System.out.println("list elements are "+dialogRemover.size());

}

public void setSelectedPerson(Person selectedPerson) {
    this.selectedPerson = selectedPerson;
    String test = this.selectedPerson.getName();

        if(!dialogRemover.containsValue("Jag:"+String.valueOf(this.selectedPerson.getId())) ){
            dialogRemover.put(personList.indexOf(this.getSelectedPerson()),"Jag:"+String.valueOf(this.selectedPerson.getId()));
        }
        RequestContext context1 = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();          
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : dialogRemover.entrySet()) {
            context1.execute("PF('"+entry.getValue()+"').show();");
        }       
}
```

}